# Forecast with STL and regressors (using R package forecast)

Tags: r, regression, forecasting

I would like to use the stlf forecast function from the R package forecast (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) and include regressors in the model.

Question 1: This can only be done using "" method="arima"  "" - right?

Question 2: For the model calibration the parameter "xreg" should work but how can I enter the new data for th forecast? "newxreg" did not work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forecast.stl()` function does not allow for regressors. If you include an `xreg` argument with `method="arima"`, it will be used in the fitted model, but not in the forecasts. You could modify the `forecast.stl()` function to handle this.