# STL Forecasting (ARIMA) with regressors?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima

I had a question about whether the forecast package in R allows you to use new data for forecasting when modeling with STL + Arima? I found a question from 7 years ago [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45018/forecast-with-stl-and-regressors-using-r-package-forecast), but was wondering if anything has changed since then? I've looked at the documentation and I'm a bit confused on xreg vs newxreg.

Comment: Why not read the package documentation?

Comment: I have RTM, and I'm not too clear on the difference between xreg and newxreg.

Comment: This link https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/hts-with-regressors/ might help; basically, `xreg` are the values of the regressors used in fitting the model, i.e., the historical values of the regressors, and `newxreg` are the values of those same regressors used in generating forecasts, i.e., the future values of the regressors.

Comment: (Using panda) It would appear that using `xreg=NewDataDF` and `newxreg=NewDataDF, h=len(NewDataDF.index)` in the forecasting arguments leads to the same forecast.

Comment: I think `newxreg` defaults to `xreg` if there's no explicit argument passed.